# MYSQL index faster by adding in the query field not in the index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I can't understand the following index behaviour of mysql,

the following query took 25 second and return 64776:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Analisi analisi0_
  INNER JOIN Paziente paziente3_ ON analisi0_.ID_PAZIENTE = paziente3_.ID_PAZIENTE
WHERE 1 = 1
 AND   paziente3_.nome LIKE 'MARIA%';
```

the following query took 7 second and return always 64776:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Analisi analisi0_
  INNER JOIN Paziente paziente3_ ON analisi0_.ID_PAZIENTE = paziente3_.ID_PAZIENTE
WHERE 1 = 1
 AND   paziente3_.nome LIKE 'MARIA%'
AND   ( paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA > 0  ||   paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA is NULL);
```

the explain for the first slow query is:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  paziente3_      range   PRIMARY,IDX_NOME    IDX_NOME    123     178176  100 Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  analisi0_       ref FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE 4   elettroforesi_light.paziente3_.ID_PAZIENTE  1   100 Using index
```

while the explain for the second query is:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  paziente3_      range   PRIMARY,IDX_NOME,IDX_DATA_NASCITA   IDX_NOME    123     178176  50.07   Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR
1   SIMPLE  analisi0_       ref FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE 4   elettroforesi_light.paziente3_.ID_PAZIENTE  1   100 Using index
```

index on table PAZIENTE:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
paziente    0   PRIMARY 1   ID_PAZIENTE A   1404534             BTREE       
paziente    1   IDX_COGNOME 1   COGNOME A   161711          YES BTREE       
paziente    1   IDX_NOME    1   NOME    A   169702          YES BTREE       
paziente    1   IDX_DATA_NASCITA    1   DATA_NASCITA    A   15513           YES BTREE       
paziente    1   IDX_SESSO   1   ID_SESSO    A   1               BTREE       
paziente    1   FK_PAZIENTE_SPECIE  1   ID_SPECIE   A   1               BTREE
```

and index on table ANALISI:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
analisi 0   PRIMARY 1   ID_ANALISI  A   1454102             BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE 1   ID_PAZIENTE A   1454102             BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_SESSIONE 1   ID_SESSIONE A   56498               BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_PATOLOGICO   1   ID_PATOLOGICO   A   1           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE 1   ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE A   1               BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_MODIFICA  1   ID_UTENTE_MODIFICA  A   1           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE   1   ID_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE   A   1           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE 1   ID_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE A   1           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_LINK 1   ID_ANALISI_LINK A   1           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_IFE  1   ID_ANALISI_IFE  A   227         YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_NOTA 1   ID_ANALISI_NOTA A   17132           YES BTREE       
analisi 1   FK_ANALISI_ANALISI_DATI 1   ID_ANALISI_DATI A   1454102         YES BTREE       
analisi 1   IDX_CAMPIONE    1   CAMPIONE    A   102648          YES BTREE       
analisi 1   IDX_REPARTO 1   REPARTO A   132         YES BTREE
```

I really can't understand why the result is better if both uery use IDX_NOME and IDX_NOME doesn't include DATA_NASCITA.

Comment: Have you run both queries multiple times in varying orders, and rebooted the system intermittently while testing? Don't underestimate the benefits of caches both of query results by MySQL and disk contents by the underlying OS.

Comment: yes, it is a ripetitive behaviour, tested at least 20 times

Comment: `Using index condition` and `Using MRR`.  Adding the additional tests is changing the query plan, engaging two additional optimizations... for no obvious reason.  Are these tables InnoDB? If so, what do you get from `SELECT @@INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE;`?

Comment: Yes, INNODB tables:    -->   SELECT @@INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE;    -->   8388608

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot There is an obvious reason for using MRR in the second case and not the first case.   In the first case, only columns from the IDX_NOME index is needed (Ref. "Using index")   In that case, MRR does not apply since its whole purpose is to improve accesses to the base table.

Comment: @oysteing yes, that *is* rather obvious... I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Like` is the costly operation in **mysql** ,In second query there are more filters on query so filters get executed first which gives you a less number of results and then like is applied over those results .

Since in first query the result after first query filter  may contains more number of records which get reduced in second query when you add

```
( paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA > 0  ||   paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA is NULL);
```

as a **`AND`** filter on query.

Comment: but "and ( paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA > 0  ||   paziente3_.DATA_NASCITA is NULL)" is not a true filter by my point of view.

Comment: @Etantonio  
there can be some vales in DATA_NASCITA which contains value which are not null or not > 0, if you run query if you remove the like part from both queries you can easily see the difference in counts of both queries. both will be having diffrent result..

Comment: Following two query have same result: 1408146,             
select count(*) from paziente where 1=1
AND   ( paziente.DATA_NASCITA > 0  ||   paziente.DATA_NASCITA is NULL);

                          select count(*) from paziente;

     So seems there is no filter from condition 

AND   ( paziente.DATA_NASCITA > 0  ||   paziente.DATA_NASCITA is NULL);

Thanks for your time.
 
select count(*) from paziente;

Comment: Also, note, `LIKE` is **not** a costly operation when the search expression is constructed anchored-left with the wildcard on the the right. `'THIS%'` is perfectly fine, and uses the index for a range scan. `'%THIS%'` is expensive, requires a full scan and cannot use an index.

Comment: @Etantonio then it will be due to the DATA_NASCITA index field since in second query we have two indexes for query which makes it faster
and since in second query it uses MRR as well because of the indxes IDX_NOME,IDX_DATA_NASCITA  ,The motivation for Disk-sweep MRR is to reduce the number of random disk accesses and instead achieve a more sequential scan of the base table data

Comment: 1. Since both queries return 64776, the extra filter has no impact. 2.  `DATA_NASCITA` is not available in the index, so it takes _extra_ work to fetch that value, thereby slowing things down.  3. MySQL rarely uses two indexes for on select, and `EXPLAIN` would indicate it by saying "index merge", which it did not.  (That's 3 incorrect things in this 'answer'; the final point about disk accesses is the _correct_ thing.)

Answer (score 0):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mrr-optimization.html

Note that it gathers all 178K (or maybe only 64K) values of `ID_PAZIENTE`, sorts them, then does the lookups into the other table.

This implies to me that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small.  That setting should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  Increase it if possible; that will speed up most queries, and probably make both of these queries run in less than 7 seconds.

Comment: Small correction: "sorts them, then does the lookups into the other table".  That description better fits Batch Key Access (BKA).  For MRR, the sorting happens before looking up the rows in the base table to evaluate the condition on DATA_NASCITA.  However, in this case MRR will have the same effect as BKA because the index used for the other table is sorted on the primary key of the first table.  In other words, MRR on the first table makes the accesses to the FK_ANALISI_PAZIENTE index sequential.   I agree that if you have such IO issues on index access, your buffer pool is way too small.